# How do I conditionally change the colour of a cell in Google sheets, based on the cell before?

Tags: google-sheets, formatting

I want to colour a cell C5 in Google sheets red, if it is greater than the cell B5 before it. Can I do this for the whole sheet, using conditional formatting?

To be clearer: I want to do this for every column, so e.g. make C7 red if it's greater than B7, make E5 red if it's greater than D5, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use formula on range `B5:B`

```
=C5>B5
```

[image]

Comment: I don't understand was this means.

Comment: @user242318 see the picture

Comment: Thank you! But I want to do this for every column, so make C7 red if it's greater than B7, make E5 red if it's greater than D5, etc. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @user242318 formula is same only range will be B5:Z